# Select an option in a script when calling the script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to select the options for [this script](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25563756) via command line.

For example I want to choose option 2, but this requires entering the number and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I tried to enter `./install.sh < 2`, but got the error `Invalid selection. Installation aborted.`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: echo -ne "2\n1\n/var/www/\nlocalhost\nradius\nradius123\nlocalhost\nconntrack\nconn123\nroot\nwww-data\ny\ny\ny\ny" | ./install.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these solutions work:

```
./install.sh <<< 2
echo 2 | ./install.sh
```

For multiple options use e.g.:

```
echo -e "2\n3\n1" | ./install.sh
```

In your case that would be:

```
echo -ne "2\n1\n/var/www/html\nlocalhost\nradius\nradius123\nlocalhost\nconntrack\nconn123\nroot\nwww-data\ny\ny\ny\ny" | ./install.sh
```

If you use this way of entering options it's crucial that you specify **all** options needed, it won't work (this way) to just specify the first two and leave the others open for the user to choose.

More about here strings (`<<<`) can be found on [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) and  [Command line: <<< instead of <<](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of).

Comment: where is the documentation for "<<<"? is there also a ">>>"?